# A valid method of finding limits in two variables functions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was wondering if in finding the limit of a two variables function (say, $F(x,y)$), I can choose the path by let $y=f(x)$, then find the limit in the same way of that in one variable functions.

For example,
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+xy+y^2}
$$

(It has no limit there by choosing first $y=0$ and then $y=x$)

So I'm asking if the following procedures are correct:

Let $y=f(x)$ where $f(0)=0$ since the function passes $(0,0)$

The function then becomes:
$$
\frac{xf(x)}{x^2 + xf(x) +f(x)^2}
$$
Then it's an indeterminate form $[0/0]$, so I differentiate,
$$
\frac{xf'(x)+f(x)}{2x + xf'(x)+f(x) +2f(x)f'(x)}
$$
Then it's still $[0/0]$ so I differentiate again,
$$\frac{xf''(x)+2f'(x)}{2+xf''(x)+2f'(x)
+2f(x)f"(x)+2f'(x)^2}$$

By substituting $x=0$, I get
$$\lim F(x,y) = \frac{2f'(x)}{2+2f'(x)+2f'(x)^2}$$

Since $f'(x)$ depends on the path I choose, the limit depends on the path I choose also.
Thus, the limit at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

So that's all, the question I have are

1. is this a valid method to determine existence of limits?
2. is this a valid method to find the limit?

(My teacher says it wont work for 2.) but I'm still unclear about his explanations)

(Sorry if I made any mistake or this is a very stupid question, I'm very new to this site and this is my first question, thank you in advance!)

Answer (score 2):

If the limit does not exist, you can find two paths that disagree. However, in case the limit does exit, your failure to find such paths is not a proof of anything. You will need to show that the limits are the same for **all** paths.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your efforts, this is something that every student tries to do while studying calculus of several variables. However it is a rather poor idea. Let me explain.

In the definition of limits, the two independent variables that describe your function $F$ are free to approach the limit point *as they wish*. Therefore **any attempt to constrain them** will be useful only to disprove the existence of the limit. As you know, if two different paths produce two different limits, the limit cannot exist. On the contrary, a functional relation like $y=f(x)$ will not suffice, since the point $(x,y)$ can approach another point in infinitely many other ways. Limits are characterized in terms of neighborhoods, and neighborhoods are not easily described in terms of graphs like $y=f(x)$. Although a curve can fill a square, a neighborhood is a very... thick object, while a differentiable graph is rather... thin.

To summarize: use paths only to disprove. If you need to prove, you must keep $x$ and $y$ completely independent.